# Url html form open in webview android

Tags: java, android, html, webview

How to open some url which is consisting html code in webview . My html url :

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('click_form').submit();"> <form action="https://my.click.uz/pay/" method="post" id="click_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="7696">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_USER_ID" value="9469">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_SERVICE_ID" value="11140">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_TRANS_ID" value="510">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_TRANS_AMOUNT" value="1612481">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_TRANS_NOTE" value="Оплата для заказа - 510">
    <input type="hidden" name="SIGN_TIME" value="2018-07-20 14:02:21">
    <input type="hidden" name="SIGN_STRING" value="12a4ad19258d57dbaa39e0fa78c7e92d"> </form>
```

Comment: symbols 'click_form' consist "click_form"

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
  });
</script>
```